# Example of a topological space with a subset $A$ such that $A''\not\subseteq A'$

Tags: general-topology

I proved that if a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is metrizable and $A ⊆ X$, than $A'' ⊆ A'$.

Now I'm trying to find an a example of $(X, \tau)$ which is not metrizable and $A ⊆ X$ such that $A'' \nsubseteq A'$ (this is a problem from a textbook, so such an example surely exists).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please remind us what $A'$ means, and when you say $\not\subseteq$ does that include $\not=$?

Comment: $A'$ usually denotes the *derived set* of $A$, i.e., the set of accumulation points of $A$.

Comment: Indeed, $A'$ is the set of accumulation points of  $A$, and $\not\subseteq$ does include $\not=$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the indiscrete topology on two elements.

Comment: With the coarse (a.k.a. indiscrete) topology on $X=\{a,b\}$  and $A=\{a\}$ the only $p\in X$ such that every nbhd $U$ of $p$ contains a point $q\in A\backslash \{p\}$ is $p=b$. So $A'=\{b\}$. Similarly $A''=\{b\}'=\{a\}.$